# how to use favicons in pywebkitgtk

Tags: python, webkit, pygtk

I would like to retrieve the favicon for each web page visited and place it next to the tab label in my notebook containing a webkit webview.  However, I am finding nothing regarding how to obtain the favicon in pywebkitgtk, (once I have the icon, I know how to place it).  I've seen some functions for doing this in the C version of webkit. Is it possible in python or should I start over in C?  If it is possible, what functions are used?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but perhaps this will help. http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitFaviconDatabase.html